# get all packets from Interfaces

Tags: python, networking, wireshark

I use `Wireshark` , In this application we can see all packets comes form **Interfaces**.

Now I want to get **all** this packets form python script .Is there any way to do that?

Comment: This will solve all problems - http://pycap.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your capture as a pcap file and then open it using
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcapfile